# Execute over 1000 insert statements in 1 string

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python

I thought this one would be simple, but for whatever reason the data isn't in the table when the script is done. I am generating a string of over 1000 queries, currently 1131, and they are separated by ";".

This string is created by a simple for loop:

```
query = ""

for: #loop condition
    query += "INSERT INTO Results (col1, col2, col3, col4, pass) VALUES ('%s', %s, %s, %s, 0);" % (val1, val2, val3, val4)
logger.debug("SQL Query = %s" % query)

try:
    cursor.execute(query, multi=True)
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    try:
        logger.error("MySQL Error [%d]: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1]))
        dbinit.cnx.rollback()
        cursor.close()
        dbinit.cnx.close()
    except IndexError:
        logger.error("MySQL Error: %s" % str(e))
        dbinit.cnx.rollback()
        cursor.close()
        dbinit.cnx.close()

dbinit.cnx.commit()
cursor.close()
dbinit.cnx.close()
```

I'm not getting any errors, and when I print the string, it prints just fine. I can even copy/paste whats printed, and run the sql commands all at once and it runs just fine, so I don't have any bad queries. Any help is appreciated, because I am stumped. I know there are alternate ways to go about this, but if someone could also explain why this one isn't working, so I can learn, that would be appreciated too!

**Update:** Mike's answer is right for the most part, but I just wanted to update this post with what my code ended up looking like in the end.

```
queryData=[]
for: #condition
    queryData.append((val1, val2, val3, val4, 0))

while len(queryData) != 0:
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO Results (col1, col2, col3, col4, pass) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", queryData[:999])
    del queryData[:999]
dbinit.cnx.commit()
```

Comment: Is it allowed to commit after rolling back and closing everything? Because that's what you're doing in case of exceptions. You let the execution path flow out of the try/catch statement and execute the last 3 commands. If something failed, I would at least expect an exception at that point.

Comment: It's single string, but not single query. Many providers does not allow to execute multiple statements in single query to prevent  SQL injection. You can execute it as single query if it will be like this `INSERT INTO Results (col1, col2, col3, col4, pass) VALUES ('%s', %s, %s, %s, 0), ('%s', %s, %s, %s, 0), ('%s', %s, %s, %s, 0)` ... (sry i am not python developer, but looks like it one of possible problems)

Comment: The exceptions aren't happening, so the rollbacks and closes aren't happening. The last 3 commands execute just fine if no exceptions happen, yet I still have a blank table. 

I can do more than a single statement, because I can copy/paste the string of all 1131 inserts, and execute it as a normal mysql query. You also can't have more than 1000 different VALUES in a single insert.

Comment: Are you sure you are checking the same database for records as you are attempting to insert records?

Comment: Yes.... I am sure. I only have the one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you'r tackling this the wrong way. `cursor.execute()` takes one query, prepares it and executes it with the data you provide. In this line

```
cursor.execute(query, multi=True)
```

You've omitted the second `params` argument, so there's no data to execute with.

You seem to be assembling 1000+ queries as a single string. You could perhaps do this with `cursor.query()`, but that (if it works) will cause the server to parse and prepare essentially the same query 1000+ times, which is less than efficient. In any case, many MySQL classes specifically prohibit assembling multiple queries this way.

What you need is `cursor.executemany(query, data)` which constructs a single query, with multiple value sets, one for each row of your`data`.

I'm not a Python developer, and I cant see where you're getting your data from, but this is the example from the [MySQL reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html), reworked:

```
data = [
  ('col1-1', 1,2,3),
  ('col1-2', 4,5,6),
  ('col1-3', 7,8,9),
]
stmt = "INSERT INTO Results (col1, col2, col3, col4, pass) VALUES ('%s', %s, %s, %s, 0)"
cursor.executemany(stmt, data)
```

You can add your own exception handling. Hopefully, that will get you started.

Note: there's no limit to the number of value sets you can insert this way, but there **is** a limit to the length of the string you can create, which by default is 1Mb. If your requirements exceed this you could batch the inserts to, say, 500 at a time and run several queries (3 queries is still better than 1500!) or look at the `cursor.MySQLCursorPrepared` class which parses the query once and executes for each set of data you send.

Comment: The problem with using cursor.executemany() is that mysql doesn't support more than 1000 values in a single insert, and I have 1131 right now, and expect that to grow. I did cursor.execute(query, multi=True) because the string query already has the data in it (look at the way I am constructing my string), and adding multi=True is supposed to allow cursor.execute to execute multiple queries from the same string. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

Comment: `cursor.executemany()` isn't including the values in a single `insert`. It's sending the query once for the server to parse, then executing it as many times as you have values. Your approach is similar, except that the server has to parse the whole query 1000+ times.

Comment: That is not what the mysql connector docs are saying. It is saying execute many is a single insert, with many values. `INSERT INTO employees (first_name, hire_date)
VALUES ('Jane', '2005-02-12'), ('Joe', '2006-05-23'), ('John', '2010-10-03')` is their example, so if I needed to insert more than 1000 name/date pairs, it wouldn't be supported. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html

Comment: My apologies - I misread the MySQL docs. The `MySQLCursorPrepared` class does what I suggested. Nevertheless, although MySQL may have a limit, there's no suggestion in the Python connector docs that the connector has a limit. It could be sending the data in batches of less than 1000. Have you tried it?

Comment: The script is rather long, but I did make the change as you suggest, and it is running, I will report back.

Comment: I've update my answer to correct my misunderstanding. See my note about the limits.

Comment: https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/332 cursor.executemany is just execute done repeatedly...Therefore there is no performance boost.